# Remove same name array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Here is my foreach

```
<?php 
    foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
        echo "<PRE>";
        print_r($_product->getData());
    } 

    ?>
```

foreach Array Output:-

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 85
    [name] => Round Bur

)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 86
    [name] => testile Bur

)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 87
    [name] => Shovel

)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 88
    [name] => Round Bur

)
```

I want to remove the same name array under foreach for example

Actual Output

```
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 85
    [name] => Round Bur

)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 86
    [name] => testile Bur

)
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 87
    [name] => Shovel

)
```

How to remove the last 1 arrays because of a name as same. please give me a solution

Comment: if you only want to remove last element then use [array_pop()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_pop.asp)

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya,I think it's more that the last one (in the example) is the only duplicate, this may not always be the case.

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya that won't solve the issue if the dupe was placed as the first and second elements in the array

Comment: not only last....!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: @treyBake, problem is that this is an array of objects.

Comment: @NigelRen conversion is a thing

Comment: @NigelRen `$array = (array) $object`

Comment: @treyBake, as they are using `$_product->getData()`, I would assume this isn't just a plain object and the data may not be public.

Comment: @NigelRen what makes you assume that? and I also realised the output isn't clear. Is that example output of a singular `print_r()` or is it the output after this foreach code?

Comment: is the output you posted an example of a single iteration in the loop or is it output after the loop?

Comment: @treyBake, the code clearly shows the `print_r($_product->getData());` inside the `foreach()` loop.

Comment: @NigelRen it does, which means the dupe target is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all the results in an array, only adding them if the `name`doesn't already exist:

```
$products = array();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product){
    $product = $_product->getData();
    if (!in_array($product['name'], array_column($products, 'name'))) {
        $products[] = $product;
    }
} 
echo "<PRE>";
print_r($products);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can splice repeated row which contains the same value:

```
$res_ar = [];     // resultant array
$ar_names = [];   // array of unique names 

foreach($ar as $ind => $row){
    if (in_array($row['name'],$ar_names)){   // if name was before
        array_splice($ar,$ind,1);            // remove element by its index
    } else {
        $ar_names[] = $row['name'];          // add new name to the unique array of names
        $res_ar[] = $row;                    // saving row with new name value
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/JR52I)

Implementation for your case looks like next:

```
$res_ar = [];
$ar_names = [];

foreach ($_productCollection as $ind => $_product){

       $row = (array)$_product->getData();

       if (in_array($row['name'], $ar_names)){
           array_splice($_productCollection,$ind,1);
       } else {
           $ar_names[] = $row['name'];
           $res_ar[] = $_product;
       } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One last version, just keep a track of the names added, but also add the original to the output rather than the array of data...

```
$output = [];
$existingNames = [];
foreach ($_productCollection as $product){
    $productName = $product->getData()['name'];
    if ( !isset($existingNames[$productName]))  {
        $existingNames[$productName] = true;
        $output[] = $product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird considering it essentially works the same way as the second answer which got an upvote. happy to compensate...

Comment: @Nick, thanks, it's more of a case if there is something wrong with my code I'd rather people say.  Although sometimes it may be someone messing around :-/

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more. But for the most part that doesn't seem to be how SO works...